# I've recently created this project and its showing cannot resolve R , how to solve this problem

Tags: java, android, xml

i just started a new project for that I created a new project file ,as soon that project opend , gradle started as soon gradle ended its showin error in java that cannot resolve symbol R

```
package com.example.android.testting;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

color.xml:

[image: color.xml]

error code:

[image: error here's the file click]

Comment: try build project and share your build error in build tab

Answer (score 0):

It gives error because your R is not defied.  You have to import this R. Class if  it not work then please remove setContentView line and rewrite it by ownself it will import all class

Answer (score 0):

Check the `colors.xml`

you can not build your project because something wrong with your color.xml as error says

> ResourceException: C:\Users\Sunay\AndroidStudioProjects\testting\app\src\main\res\values\colors.xml:6:43: Error: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity. at

Comment: <application>
    <component name="RecentProjectsManager">
        <option name="recentPaths">
            <list>
                <option value="$USER_HOME$/AndroidStudioProjects/COFFEEAPP2" />
                <option value="$USER_HOME$

Comment: i tried to understand it and found that there is a problem in colors.xml i've provided the file up

Comment: @SunayKundalwal delete all this lines in colors.xml